# Is there a way to prevent copy-on-modify when modifying attributes?

Tags: r, matrix, copy

I am surprised that a copy of the matrix is made in the following code:

```
> (m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    7   10
[2,]    2    5    8   11
[3,]    3    6    9   12
> tracemem(m)
[1] "<000001E2FC1E03D0>"
> str(m)
 int [1:3, 1:4] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
> attr(m, "dim") <- 4:3
tracemem[0x000001e2fc1e03d0 -> 0x000001e2fcb05008]: 
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    5    9
[2,]    2    6   10
[3,]    3    7   11
[4,]    4    8   12
> str(m)
 int [1:4, 1:3] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Is it useful? Is it avoidable?

---

EDIT: I do not have the same results as GKi.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19041)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252    LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3   
> m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
> tracemem(m)
[1] "<000001F8DB2C7D90>"
> attr(m, "dim") <- c(4, 3)
tracemem[0x000001f8db2c7d90 -> 0x000001f8db2d93f0]:
```

One difference is that I do not use BLAS library...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using R 3.6.3 and indeed a copy is made. To change an attribute without making a copy, you can use the `setattr` function of the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)

m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
.Internal(inspect(m))

setattr(m, "dim", c(4L,3L))
.Internal(inspect(m))
```

Comment: So it is avoidable. But is it useful? And can you tell why GKi seems not ot have the same results?

Comment: @pietrodito GKi uses another version of R. Yes it is useful to avoid the copy. I used this way to change an attribute of a big matrix, otherwise R threw the error "Cannot allocate...".

Comment: I meant: is it useful in some cases for R to make that copy? I am also using R 4.0.3 and a copy is made... There is something we do not understant or point clearly

Comment: Copy-on-modify is the overwhelmingly most common copying mode in R; if you want to modify without copying (call these "shallow copies", mutable objects, access by reference, whatever), you have to go out of your way (make the changes within compiled {C,C++} code, or use the `set*` features of `data.table`, or use environments or reference classes). While copy-on-modify can be wasteful (if you don't really need to keep the original object unchanged), it's much safer than accessing by reference, where it's up to the user to make sure they don't modify an object by accident.

Comment: It would be interesting to locate the change in R between 3.6.3 and 4.0.x. I looked briefly in the [NEWS file](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/NEWS.html) and couldn't find anything relevant. (I believe that such changes would be listed in this file and not in any older NEWS files since 3.6.3 was the last release before 4.0.0.) Since this is a fairly subtle difference, it might have gotten changed as a side effect of something else and not explicitly noted in NEWS ...

Comment: @Ben Bolker: I have R 4.0.3 and a copy is made. I guess something is wrong with GKi answer

Answer (score 2):

In my case it is not making a copy of the data:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
.Internal(inspect(m))
#@250ff98 13 INTSXP g0c4 [REF(1),ATT] (len=12, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
#ATTRIB:
#  @38da270 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [REF(1)] 
#    TAG: @194d610 01 SYMSXP g0c0 [MARK,REF(1171),LCK,gp=0x4000] "dim" (has value)
#    @38c3d88 13 INTSXP g0c1 [REF(65535)] (len=2, tl=0) 3,4

attr(m, "dim") <- 4:3
.Internal(inspect(m))
#@250ff98 13 INTSXP g0c4 [REF(1),ATT] (len=12, tl=0) 1,2,3,4,5,...
#ATTRIB:
#  @38da270 02 LISTSXP g0c0 [REF(1)] 
#    TAG: @194d610 01 SYMSXP g0c0 [MARK,REF(1171),LCK,gp=0x4000] "dim" (has value)
#    @38d9978 13 INTSXP g0c0 [REF(65535)]  4 : 3 (expanded)
```

It was `@250ff98` and is afterwards still there. It is only changing the *dim* from `@38c3d88` to `@38d9978`.

```
sessionInfo()
#R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
#Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
#
#Matrix products: default
#BLAS:   /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
#LAPACK: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so
#
#locale:
# [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
# [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
# [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
# [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
# [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
#
#attached base packages:
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#
#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

The same with `tracemem`.

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
tracemem(m)
#[1] "<0x289ff98>"
attr(m, "dim") <- 4:3
tracemem(m)
#[1] "<0x289ff98>"
```

But if you make an `str(m)` in between it makes currently a copy:

```
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
tracemem(m)
#[1] "<0x28a01c8>"
str(m)
# int [1:3, 1:4] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
attr(m, "dim") <- 4:3
#tracemem[0x28a01c8 -> 0x2895608]:
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit the output of `inspect`?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a documentation for `inspect` and `.Internal` says: *Only true R wizards should even consider using this function...*. I'm using it as `tracemem` works only when R was compiled with `--enable-memory-profiling`. I hope that everything starting with `@` will be an address.

Comment: Have you seen that I do not have the same results as yours with the same version of R...

Comment: Yes, so I asked [Why is R making a copy-on-modification on one Computer but not on another Computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64765550/10488504)