# Why is R making a copy-on-modification after using str?

Tags: r

I was wondering why R is making a copy-on-modification after using `str`.

I create a `matrix`. I can change its `dim`, one element or even all. No copy is made. But when a call `str` R is making a copy during the next modification operation on the Matrix. Why is this happening?

```
m <- matrix(1:12, 3)
tracemem(m)
#[1] "<0x559df861af28>"
dim(m) <- 4:3
m[1,1] <- 0L
m[] <- 12:1
str(m)
# int [1:4, 1:3] 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 ...
dim(m) <- 3:4  #Here after str a copy is made
#tracemem[0x559df861af28 -> 0x559df838e4a8]:
dim(m) <- 3:4
str(m)
# int [1:3, 1:4] 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 ...
dim(m) <- 3:4 #Here again after str a copy
#tracemem[0x559df838e4a8 -> 0x559df82c9d78]:
```

Also I was wondering why a copy is made when having a Task Callback.

```
TCB <- addTaskCallback(function(...) TRUE)
m <- matrix(1:12, nrow = 3)
tracemem(m)
#[1] "<0x559dfa79def8>"
dim(m) <- 4:3  #Copy on modification
#tracemem[0x559dfa79def8 -> 0x559dfa8998e8]:
removeTaskCallback(TCB)
#[1] TRUE
dim(m) <- 4:3  #No copy
```

sessionInfo()

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so
LAPACK: /usr/local/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_AT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_AT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_AT.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_AT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_AT.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_AT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_AT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3
```

This is a follow up question to [Is there a way to prevent copy-on-modify when modifying attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64695984/10488504).

I start R with `R --vanilla` to have a clean session.

Comment: Are you running the R code with Rgui?

Comment: No I run it in a text-terminal (xterm).

Comment: Can you try with Rscript?

Comment: Rscript comes to the same result.

Comment: intriguing feature!  would it be worth posting to the R-help (or -devel) mailing list?  I would be interested to know what's causing this

Comment: If you're compiling from source, you might want to add some good old tracing messages (maybe with `R_ShowMessage`?) to [the source code of `dim<-`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/attrib.c#L1177) and see if different paths are being taken. Definitely consider posting to R devel, tracking references seems to have some [intricacies](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Confused-about-NAMED-td4103326.html), but I'm not sure if different compilers could affect that.

Comment: This is pretty interesting - I'm in the machine B camp, on MacOS through iterm. Would love to see what R devel has to say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have asked this question on [R-help](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2020-November/469508.html) as suggested by @sam-mason in the comments.

The answer from Luke Tierney solved the issue with `str`:

> As of R 4.0.0 it is in some cases possible to reduce reference counts
> internally and so avoid a copy in cases like this. It would be too
> costly to try to detect all cases where a count can be dropped, but it
> this case we can do better. It turns out that the internals of
> pos.to.env were unnecessarily creating an extra reference to the call
> environment (here in a call to exists()). This is fixed in r79528.
> Thanks.

And related to `Task Callback`:

> It turns out there were some issues with the way calls to the
> callbacks were handled. This has been revised in R-devel in r79541.
> This example will no longere need to duplicate in R-devel.
>
> Thanks for the report.