# R modify-in-place

Tags: r

I am reading Hadley's Advanced R, and I have a question regarding modify in place. In the section [Modify-in-place](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/names-values.html#modify-in-place), it is mentioned when objects have single binding they are modified in place. Also reflected by the image, by mentioning that `v` has same id.
[image]

But when I tried to recreate this example in my pc, I get different address:

```r
l = c(1,2,3,4)
tracemem(l)
#> [1] "<0000000018166270>"

l[[1]] = 2
#> tracemem[0x0000000018166270 -> 0x0000000013b34850]: eval eval withVisible withCallingHandlers doTryCatch tryCatchOne tryCatchList tryCatch try handle timing_fn evaluate_call <Anonymous> evaluate in_dir block_exec call_block process_group.block process_group withCallingHandlers process_file <Anonymous> <Anonymous> <Anonymous> <Anonymous> do.call saveRDS withCallingHandlers doTryCatch tryCatchOne tryCatchList doTryCatch tryCatchOne tryCatchList tryCatch
```

I was expecting `l` to have same object address (as shown in the book), perhaps I misunderstood?
So the question I have is: How does modify in place work in R?

Comment: What version of R do you have?

Comment: Have also a look at [Why is R making a copy-on-modification after using str?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64765550/10488504).

Comment: I have version 4.0.2

Comment: I have 4.1.0 and in my case it makes modify-in-place for the given example.

Comment: Are you using RStudio? Try using just the basic R console. I can't replicate with `R 4.0.5` and `RStudio 1.4.1106`. There is no copy for me.

Comment: I think until `4.0.3` it makes sometimes a copy on modification which was fixed by Luke Tierney for newer version.

Comment: Okay, when I tried using basic R console as suggested by @MrFlick, I got the same address

Comment: Things like the RStudio Environment viewer can also hold on to references to variables which prevent copy-in-place. But efforts have been made to reduce that issue in more recent versions.

Comment: Facepalm moment, I missed a section while reading advanced R, but hadley also mentions the same thing that RStudio may give different result and recommends to either use Rterminal of Rmarkdown